# Don't see my image in Jssor Gallery

Tags: jquery, image, css, jssor

I have a problem with a jssor fade gallery..The gallery work, but only the image on the library are view correctly in the gallery, for example 
if  my image with the same dimension, the image isn't resize and i can see only a part

Comment: code? we need more info to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can put anything in your slide. For example, you can put an image in your slide.

```
<div>
    <img src="url" />
    <!-- and you can put something else as well -->
</div>
```

But if you specify `u="image"` for an image element in a slide, jssor slider will fill the image (according to $FillMode option) in the slide.

```
<div>
    <img u="image" src="url" />
    <!-- and you can put something else as well -->
</div>
```